# Somethings missing

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**In the puzzle below I've correctly placed an image in three different cells. Your task is to correctly place images in all the remaining (19) cells and of course, as usual, provide a good explanation why it's correct.**

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

*The other two:* **2015, 2022**

Comment: The apostrophe is missing. They are placed where a letter has been removed in a contraction. In this case the 'i' in 'something *is* missing' has been removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The empty cells should be filled as follows:

> [image: Cells filled with directors' faces]
>
>  [image: The final cells filled with directors' faces]

Because the man in the original image is:

> [**Mohana Krishna Indraganti**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohana_Krishna_Indraganti), director of the 2020 movie, [*V*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(2020_film)).

If we notice that:

> 'V' is the Roman numeral for '5' then count up the slots in the top image, we can see that there are sufficient spaces available to enter in the Roman numeral representations of all the numbers 1-9 (I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX). Moreover, the bottom image looks very much like it might be describing a **magic square** (horizontals, verticals and diagonals all indicated), with a sum of 15.

The positioning of this man's image confirms this - we can find a valid possibility that we probably need to complete:

> Top row: 2, 7, 6
>  Middle: 9, 5, 1
>  Bottom row: 4, 3, 8
>
>  Or, in Roman numerals:
>
>  II, VII, VI
>  IX, V, I
>  IV, III, VIII
>
>  Note that these characters correspond perfectly with the available slots.

So what to fill it with? Thematically - and making use of the line saying "The other two: 2015, 2022" - we can find:

> movies called '[*I*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(2015_film))' from 2015 (directed by [**S. Shankar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Shankar)), and '[*X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_(2022_film))' from 2022 (directed by [**Ti West**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti_West)).
>
>  So if we use the directors' faces to represent the Roman numerals from their movie titles, we can complete the puzzle as in the image at the top of this answer, with digits 1-9 appearing in the magic square and 'XV' (15) in the puzzle key to show what each run of 3 digits should sum to.

Comment: Faster than expected. Well done!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Same thought here! I think having solved another of yours recently which involved numbers helped. I looked through the pictured person's back catalogue and one title immediately leaped out at me. It then took a little thought to work out what might go in the adjacent boxes, and once I hit upon you-know-what and the rest of the slot counts matched up perfectly, I realised that had to be it :)

Comment: I see. Just before you answered I was planning to make an edit (thinking it hadn't enough info) , to give a small clue, as to which movie I refered to but then you answered :)